# handling combobox in datagridview in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi i have a datagrid in window form called "dataGridView1" and i have combobox in the dataGridView1; i am displaying the data in combobox from database and all data loads in that combobox when window loads. i have function LoadModels for that. there is one column ModelName which i want to display and in valuemember there will be MedelID, so i want when user select any model from combobox then it give me id of that model called "ModelID".

```
public frmBikeOrder()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    ControlBox = false;
    LoadModels();
}

private void LoadModels()
{
    RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
    List<TblBikeModel> AllModels = (from s in conn.TblBikeModels
                     select s).ToList();
    Column2.DataSource = AllModels;
    Column2.DisplayMember = "ModelName";
    Column2.ValueMember = "ModelID";
}
```

i have a function when value changes, i want the value in messagebox after combobox value change

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
       {
            ComboBox cmb =  ComboBox();
            MessageBox.Show(cmb.SelectedValue.ToString());
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
       {
            bool val = (bool)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value;
            MessageBox.Show(val.ToString());
       }
}
```

you get the selected cell using `dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0]` and it's value(is checked) with the value Property.

you can also use the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` and do:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
       {
            bool val = (bool)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
            MessageBox.Show(val.ToString());
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the property of combobox as:

```
        ModelComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "ModelID";
        ModelComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "ModelName";
```

Then ModelComboBox.SelectedValue will be ModelID.